# Main category icons in navigation drawers not visible

Tags: android

below is my xml code where vector image works on items but does not work on its parent. I have given comment for those two parents.I also wish to give colored icons there later and textcolor white.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />

</group>


<item android:title="Communicate"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share">

    <!--  above image not visible but below visible-->

    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>


<item android:title="Setting"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share">

    <!-- above image not visible but below visible -->

    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Here "Communicate " and "Setting" not showing icons

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in menu if you want to show icons also:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />

</group>


   <menu>
          <item android:title="Communicate"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>




    <menu>

        <item android:title="Setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

You can change the textcolor of all menu item using: `app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"` attribute in xml code of navigation view.

**Edit**

You will get the colored icons if you use either 
`app:itemIconTint="null"` in xml `or`
`navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);` in your java code.

Comment: It worked.but when I use vector or png images it shows in black color.is it possible via xml to give give colored icons? only for some specific item ,not all.

Comment: @Harshad yes you can use colored icons. i am editing my answer, plz check :)