# parent menu item doesn't display icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-menu, navigation-drawer

I have created a navigation menu with menu resource file. There are multiple groups and in that groups there are multiple parent and child items. With icons in each items along with parent and child. But the result doesn't show an icon having a parent item. Is there any way to display icon of parent item also? Please find my code below and share your suggestions.

```
<group android:id="@+id/catalogs">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/user_menu"
            android:title="@string/nav_catalog"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_paypal_24dp">

            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/item_wotu_user"
                    android:title="@string/nav_base_catalogue"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_paypal_24dp"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/item_super_user"
                    android:title="@string/nav_buyer_catalogue"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_paypal_24dp" />
            </menu>
        </item>

</group>
```

Comment: only sub-menu's icon can be shown in any sort of menu.. whether its a nav-menu or a option-menu

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028156/main-category-icons-in-navigation-drawers-not-visible